# What should I use to implement a shopping cart process?

Tags: 7

I'm developing a website for a group of human resource professionals.

The customer wants a way for people to go to their site and do the following:

1. If they have a job listing they want to post to the website, they'll click on a "Post a Job" link.
2. The job submitter will then fill out the content for a job posting
3. Before the job can go online, the job poster will have to pay a fee to have it posted
4. Once the payment is received, the job posts to the website

I'm curious if anyone has any experience with this, and if so, what would you use to build it? It's a fairly simple shopping cart experience I suppose. It's certainly not like a store or anything. But, I don't have previous experience with something like this.

Can anyone guide me down the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few typical solutions for implementing an online store:

- [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), or its related [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).
- [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart).

However, as per your "*Simple shopping cart experience*", it looks like none of these is what you're looking for. So here are some other modules you may want to look at (excerpts are from their project pages):

- [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart):

  > ... a very simple shopping cart / checkout process for Drupal, that just sends 2 emails after each order. Along with the shopping cart, this module also provides a block where you can view your cart's content. It's ideal for small websites with only a few products or other content types being sold, for example touristic offers.
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules):

  > Allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules).
- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag):

  > Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by the administrator.

The 'Basic Cart' implements the cart, while with the 'Rules' and 'Flag' modules you can implement appropriate business logic (which does not require any PHP coding skills).

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), then checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-the-rules-framework), organised in 7 chapters.

Possibly also the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-flag-with-nodeone) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, often considered as a natural complement to the Rules module.